# What is the proper way to return a firestore documentID in swift?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to create a function that will return a documentID given a value of a field. I am getting tired of my nested functions. Is there a simple way to have one function that returns the ID ?

Here is what I have been doing. It is an ugly pattern.

```
public class func getAccountItems(accountName:String) {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let userId: String! = defaults.string(forKey: "UserUUID")

    db.collection("Portfolios")
        .whereField("users." + userId, isEqualTo: true)
        .limit(to: 1)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                var documentID:String? = nil

                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    documentID = document.documentID

                    if(documentID != nil){

                        do {
                            let db = Firestore.firestore()

                            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                            let portfolioId: String! = defaults.string(forKey: listDocKey)

                            db.collection("Portfolios").document(portfolioId).collection("Accounts").whereField("name", isEqualTo: accountName)
                                .getDocuments(){ (querySnapshot, err) in
                                    if let err = err {
                                        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                                    } else {
                                        if querySnapshot!.documents.count == 1 {
                                            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                                                db.collection("Portfolios").document(documentID!).collection("Accounts").document(document.documentID).collection("Items")
                                                    .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                                                        if let err = err {
                                                            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                                                        } else {
                                                            var items:[INDX01FirestoreService.PortfolioItem] = []
                                                            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                                                                print("\(accountName): \(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                                                                let pi = try! FirestoreDecoder().decode(INDX01FirestoreService.PortfolioItem.self, from: document.data())

                                                                items.append(pi )
                                                            }
                                                            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AccountItemsReceived"), object: nil, userInfo: ["items": items])

                                                        }
                                                }

                                            }
                                        }else{
                                            print ("Error count is \(querySnapshot!.documents.count)")
                                        }

                                    }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Since Firestore is an async call I either do it this way or I send a notification. I don't like sending notifications all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Cant post a comment but one thing why do you have so much db references

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
```

this should give you id of the document like you have

```
documentID = document.documentID
```

Post here how your data structure looks like and what ids you want to get also have in mind you should store id in each document.

[image]

I try to help you.

Comment: yea.. since I am always searching first then working with the document, I cut and paste a bit too much. I wanted a single function that would search for an account by name and then return a reference. However, since the search is async, I can't do that. I have been using notifications for my other functions... but since a lot of my functions require the ID, I was hoping there might be a swift/firsetore trick

Comment: So you want search for users by username ? Or what is the idea ? Could you also post screenshot of your Data Structure of firebase / firestore ?

Answer (score 0):

I decided to just store the documentID in UserDefaults as that handles most of the use cases. Otherwise I do the above, search, find, then process